# How can i add UISegmentedControl programmatically in swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I stucked while designing UISegmentControl programmatically in swift 3.0 with adding target, please help me for this.

Comment: OK. If you are not able to launch your app now or it crashed please provide some code. Nobody knows about your problem with UISegmentControl.

Comment: Actually i tried this objective c code and convert it into swift3.0 but not working     

segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl (items: ["First","Second","Third"])

        segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(60, 250,200, 30)

        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

        segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "segmentedControlAction:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    self.view.addSubview(segmentedControl)